# Custom method chaining with Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my current query:

```
$cars = Cars::with('brand')->get();

$cars->map(function($cars){

    $cars->fullName = $cars->brand->brand." ".$cars->name;
    //other manipulation...
    return $cars;
});
```

I want to manipulate my collection in the model so that I can run something like `$cars = Cars::with('brand')->getWithBrand();`

How can I do this, so I don't have to write map functions for every time I run the query?

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, you don't need to use `map` to modify the Collection at all. You can use an [Eloquent accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to define attributes on a Model that don't exist in the database. In your example, you would define the following method on your `Cars` model:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    // make sure brand exists first
    if ($this->brand) {
        return $this->brand->brand.' '.$this->name;
    }

    // default if brand doesn't exist
    return $this->name;
}
```

By defining that function on your Model, that function will be called whenever you attempt to use the `full_name` attribute, as shown in the following code:

```
$car = Cars::with('brand')->first();

// this will echo the result of the getFullNameAttribute method
echo $car->full_name;
```

#### Edit

If you would also like this new attribute to automatically show up in your `toArray()` or `toJson()` output, you can add the attribute to the `$appends` property on your `Cars` model:

```
class Cars extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
    {
        // make sure brand exists first
        if ($this->brand) {
            return $this->brand->brand.' '.$this->name;
        }

        // default if brand doesn't exist
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Be aware, however, that your custom attribute depends on a related object. So, if you do something that accidentally calls `toArray()`, `toJson()`, `__toString()`, etc on a Collection of Cars that has not eager loaded the `brand` relationship, this will cause the N+1 query issue.

For example:

```
// Bad: N+1 issue because each printed Car will execute a
// separate query to get its brand to output full_name.
echo Cars::get();

// Good: No N+1 issue because all brands are already loaded.
echo Cars::with('brand')->get();
```

Comment: Do you mean $this instead of $cars in your example?

Comment: I don't think this works if you do `$car->all();` or `toArray()`

Comment: @tgun926 If you want this attribute to show up in your `toArray()` or `toJson()` output, you can add the attribute to your `$appends` property on the model. I have updated the code again to show the example.